# Какие бывают значения параметров для аннотации @SuppressWarnings в Java?

Tags: java, аннотации

Известно, что для подавления варнингов в Java используется аннотация **@SuppressWarnings**, которая в качестве параметра требует массив String[]. Т.е. не статические переменные, не enum, а просто строки.
Я знаю, что наиболее частоиспользуемое значение - "*unchecked*".
Каков полный список значений этих параметров? Он отличается в зависимости от используемой среды разработки, или одинаковый для всех?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список зависит от компилятора/IDE (как не сложно догадаться).

- Для ванильной Java (точнее компилятора Sun/Oracle/Open JDK javac), список совпадает со списком значений ключа `-Xlint` ([смотреть здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings))
- Для Intellij IDEA (включая Android Studio) - список плохо документирован, но судя по всему совпадает с [этим списком](https://gist.github.com/vegaasen/157fbc6dce8545b7f12c)
- Для Eclipse список приведен [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206001/472270)